# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Forbidden on iOS Safari

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-core, safari, http-status-code-403

I have come across a situation where some users on iPhone and occasionally desktop get a 403 Forbidden error when accessing an [Authorize] route on my site. After getting the error, even going to the Home page fails with the same error, and the Home page allows anonymous.

When iOS users go into Safari settings and delete web data cache, or delete just the data for my site, the error goes away. But then before long it's back again - sometimes within just a few hours.

I've searched for answers to this intermittent problem online but have not found a solution, and users are getting frustrated. I did find this page but I'm not sure if its related or how to implement the work-around:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore#support-older-browsers

I've also tried and failed to fix the issue as follows:

- Update Safari app (if available).
- Phone restart/reset.
- Check the URL address - the address is correct.
- Clear history, cookies and/or all web data cache.
- Reset network settings.
- My website appears to be working and configured correctly and ISP's are not blocking the service.

The process is:

- User signs in with their credentials to use the site.
- At a later point in time, sometimes just an hour or so later, they
  attempt to access a page and suddenly get the forbidden error.

Does anyone have experience with this? When I access the site on my Android phone I don't seem to have a problem, but I don't use the site much like the users need to.

I've included code below for controller **SignIn**, **Console** and **Startup.cs**

```
    [HttpPost()]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SignIn(SignIn sin)
    {
        DateTime dt = gFunc.UTCNowToLocal( string.Empty);
        try
        {
            // code for check data, model state
            // ...

            // check google recaptcha
            var GoogleRecap = _reCAPTCHAService.VerifyRecaptcha(sin.RecaptchaToken);
            if (GoogleRecap.Result.success && GoogleRecap.Result.score < 0.5)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Apply", "Captcha service determined you are not human!");
            }

            // create claims
            var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, sin.ShopToken),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, sin.ShopID.ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, sin.EmailAddress.ToLower()),                
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, gFunc.CLAIM_ROLE_SAMADHI_SHOP),
            new Claim("LastChanged", "1 Jan 2021 00:01")
        };
            if (sin.IsSignInAdmin)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, gFunc.CLAIM_ROLE_SAMADHI_SHOP_ADMIN));
            }

            // create identity
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // cookie or local            

            // create principal
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

            // authentication properties
            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true
            };

            // sign-in
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(scheme: CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal: principal, properties: authProperties);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            gFunc.ProcessError(ex);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Console", new { date = dt.ToString("d MMM yyyy"), timer = false });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = gFunc.CLAIM_ROLE_SAMADHI_SHOP)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Console(string date, bool timer)
    {
        int shop_id = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
        string token = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid).Value;
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
            dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
        Shop ss = await RepoSamadhi.GetShop(shop_id, token, dt);
        if (User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, gFunc.CLAIM_ROLE_SAMADHI_SHOP_ADMIN))            
            ss.IsAdmin = true;
        ss.IsTimerOn = timer;
        return View((_device.Type == DeviceType.Mobile) ? "ConsoleM" : "ConsoleM", ss);
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        try
        {
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
                {
                    o.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(90, 0, 0, 0);
                    o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Samadhi/SignIn/");
                    o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Samadhi/SignIn/");
                    o.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Samadhi/SignOut/");
                    // o.EventsType = typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents);
                    var defaultCallback = o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin;
                    o.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                    {
                        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/samadhi"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            context.RedirectUri = "/Samadhi/SignIn/";
                            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                        }
                        else if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/rbk"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            context.RedirectUri = "/Rbk/SignIn/";
                            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                        }
                        return defaultCallback(context);
                    };                        
                    o.Validate();
                });

            services.AddScoped<CustomCookieAuthenticationEvents>();

            services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions>(o =>
            {
                // Password settings
                o.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                o.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // Lockout settings
                o.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                o.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                o.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings
                o.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                o.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

            // add detection services container and device resolver service
            services.AddDetectionCore()
                .AddDevice();

            // google recaptcha
            services.Configure<ReCAPTCHASettings>(Configuration.GetSection("GooglereCAPTCHA"))
                .AddTransient<ReCAPTCHAService>();

            // services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAntiforgery();
            services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            gFunc.ProcessError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        try
        {
            // set file paths
            gFunc.SetLogFilePaths(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

            // environment
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();                
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            gFunc.ProcessError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we have no problem with pc access, and no problem with android access, then our program is normal.

Then this problem, after searching, many people encountered this problem. Then it means that this may be related to iOS, and it needs to be related to clear caching, or reset network settings to solve it.

*Related Blog or Articles:*

[1. Fixing iPhone XR’s ‘403 Forbidden Error’ on Safari: A Step by Step Guide](https://www.techtimes.com/articles/258406/20210325/fixing-iphone-xr-403-forbidden-error-safari-step-guide.htm)

[2. How do I fix a forbidden error 403 on Safari?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fix-a-forbidden-error-403-on-Safari)

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried most of the suggested solutions I found on the web. "First of all, we have no problem with pc access." Please note first paragraph of my post. I've also updated my post to include what I've already tried to fix the issue.

Comment: @RossKelly Where is your program deployed? IIS or Azure webapp?

Comment: it is deployed to IIS in a shared environment with access using Plesk. not using Azure in-part because I need it to be hosted in-country. I plan to try to get one of my clients to make a note of the datetime when the forbidden next occurs so I can find any error messages in the log. but log messages are often misleading. occasionally I also get the same forbidden error for an Anonymous method in a desktop environment in Google Chrome, but it's much less frequent than the iPhone issue with the [Authorize] method.